# Paypal Adaptive Payment Incomplete Status

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using the adaptive delayed chain payment. I have tested the processes using sandbox account and it was successfully executed. However, When I tested the same process by using live credentials, endpoints and live Paypal account. I got `INCOMPLETE` status for the Secondary Receiver.

[image]

Comment: Are your app ID is being granted to use Delayed Chained Payment? Also, can you check if the secondary receiver are Business or Premier verified account?